# What is the correct way to track which item is active in a tree, in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carbon-design-system

I'm using [Carbon's SideNav](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/UI-shell-left-panel/code) component as a tree navigation control for a page. The leaves can be set `active` by either an `isActive` boolean property or by adding `aria-current='page'`. If a leaf is in a submenu, the menu is expanded if any of its children are active. Active item tracking doesn't come out of the box, it has to be added. I have two questions:

1. What would be the correct way of implementing active item tracking? I can think of two ways: adding an `onClick()` to each `SideNavMenuItem` or, as I currently implemented it: putting together a reference array, then using `useEffect()` to remove the active class from all and add it to the one that is selected
2. What is the correct way of marking the active item when the containing component mounts (e.g. on a page refresh or navigating to the page via a bookmark). My reference code sets the active state by adding the required class to the menu item but the `SideNavMenu` will only open if any of its children are active - which is a property I can't set via a reference.

My current example is based on a small, 8-item tree but I will have to expand this to a much larger scale.

```
const MySidebar = () => {

  const menuRefs = useRef(new Array());

  useEffect(() => {
    const className = "bx--side-nav__link--current";
    menuRefs.current.forEach(ref => {ref.classList.remove(className)})
    const ref = menuRefs.current.filter((ref) => ref.baseURI === ref.href);
    if (ref) {
      ref[0].classList.add(className);
    }
  });

  return (
      <SideNav
      className="my-nav"
      isFixedNav
      expanded={true}
      isChildOfHeader={false}
      aria-label="Side navigation"
      >
        <SideNavItems>
          <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[0] = element} element={Link} to="page1">Page 1</SideNavMenuItem>
          <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[1] = element} element={Link} to="page2">Page 2</SideNavMenuItem>
          <SideNavMenu  title='Some submenu'>
            <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[2] = element} element={Link} to="page3">Page 3</SideNavMenuItem>
            <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[3] = element} element={Link} to="page4">Page 4</SideNavMenuItem>
            <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[4] = element} element={Link} to="page5">Page 5</SideNavMenuItem>
            <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[5] = element} element={Link} to="page6">Page 6</SideNavMenuItem>
            <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[6] = element} element={Link} to="page7">Page 7</SideNavMenuItem>
          </SideNavMenu>
          <SideNavMenuItem ref={(element) => menuRefs.current[7] = element} element={Link} to="page8">Page 8</SideNavMenuItem>
        </SideNavItems>
      </SideNav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the active item in memory is not the way to go, afais, you should infer it from the url. You could use a `hashed routes` or `route parameters` to track the active item, push it to url once clicked, use it directly from url in the component. That way it wont lose the active item on refresh, and the urls can be bookmarked and shared too.

Comment: The active item is not being kept in memory. The URL denotes which one the active item is as each item loads a certain page. What I have difficulties figuring out is how I can link the URL to the element's `isActive` property

Comment: @RekaB are you using ```ReactRouter``` ? so for example if you push the active item to search parameters, it would be sth like ```http://localhost:300/home?page=page6``` you could get the value from ```window.location.search```,  if its in the path you will have to do some string processing. If you are using react-router which is recommended, its easier, it would be ```match.params.{paramId}``` to access path params. for search same.

Comment: the issue is not determining if the page is active, it's making the SideNav element realize that. I have now resolved the issue by using `NavLink` instead of `Link` but I still need to be able to open the SideNavMenu.
I was also interested in a general best practice of to adjust properties of potentially dynamically generated children

Comment: @RekaB if you can provide a https://codesandbox.io/ minimal example, i can help.

Comment: isnt this tracking the active page? what's the issue ?

Comment: what you have done to determine if expanded seems reasonable enough, don't see a coding standard issue with your code.

Comment: a more elegant way would be to generate a nested object structure and render all your routes based off of that, then you could add ```expanded``` property in the nested children itself, which will handle dynamic ```n``` depth child routes better.

Comment: So the original question was: how would I be able to dynamically control the `isActive` property of each leaf. I got it working with the `NavLink` but I would still like to know how I could have done it differently.

Comment: Given I'm using an external library I don't have much control over how the elements are nested and I'm now having the same issue with `defaultExpanded` as I had with `isActive`: how can I set the boolean property of an element, using a method referencing itself??

Comment: As I was saying, this is all easy with a small set of items, but the version I'm currently looking at has 542 `SideNavMenu` elements and 420 `SideNavMenuItem`. I'm using the components to navigate the documentation of a rather large product.

Comment: even when using NavLink active styles are applied by ```active``` class name. theres a prop in NavLink called ```activeClassName``` where you can set a different name for it. also NavLink has isActive boolean, which if i remember correctly can be a function that returns a boolean too. you can add custom logic there. Also if you weren't using Link or NavLink you will have to apply the classes manually checking the url.

Answer (score 0):

For opening the tree/tracking items when users navigate with links inside the content div, I ended up wrapping the original `SideNavMenu` with my own component, that checks if any of the children have a link to the current location, recursively. I split the check into three methods to avoid having a field of `if` statements in any one of them. I still don't know if this is the correct approach but it works.

```
class MySideNavMenu extends React.Component {
  hasActiveChild = (child) => {
    if (child.props.element) { // leaf
      return this.props.location.pathname === child.props.to;
    }
    if (child.props.children) { // node
      return this.checkChildren(child.props.children);
    }
  };

  checkChildren = (children) => {
    return Array.isArray(children)
      ? children.some((child) => {
          return this.hasActiveChild(child);
        })
      : this.hasActiveChild(children);
  };

  isExpanded = () => {
    const children = this.props.children;
    if (children) {
      // if we have children, either a single or multiple, find if it is active
      return this.checkChildren(children);
    }

    return false;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SideNavMenu defaultExpanded={this.isExpanded()} title={this.props.title}>
        {this.props.children}
      </SideNavMenu>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MySideNavMenu);
```